# Convert and format XML to JSON on Azure Storage Account in Powershell

Tags: json, xml, powershell, format, converters

So i'm trying to convert XML files on an Azure Storage Container to JSON in the same container.
This way I'm able to read the information into an Azure SQL Database via an Azure Datafactory.
I'd like to stay clear from using Logic apps if able.

The JSON files need to be formatted.
And all this through the use of PowerShell scripting.

What i've got so far after some searching on the interwebs and shamelessly copying and pasting powershell code:

```html
#Connect-AzAccount

# Helper function that converts a *simple* XML document to a nested hashtable
# with ordered keys.
function ConvertFrom-Xml {
  param([parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] [System.Xml.XmlNode] $node)
  process {
    if ($node.DocumentElement) { $node = $node.DocumentElement }
    $oht = [ordered] @{}
    $name = $node.Name
    if ($node.FirstChild -is [system.xml.xmltext]) {
      $oht.$name = $node.FirstChild.InnerText
    } else {
      $oht.$name = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 
      foreach ($child in $node.ChildNodes) {
        $null = $oht.$name.Add((ConvertFrom-Xml $child))
      }
    }
    $oht
  }
}

function Format-Json
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Prettifies JSON output.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Reformats a JSON string so the output looks better than what ConvertTo-Json outputs.
    .PARAMETER Json
        Required: [string] The JSON text to prettify.
    .PARAMETER Minify
        Optional: Returns the json string compressed.
    .PARAMETER Indentation
        Optional: The number of spaces (1..1024) to use for indentation. Defaults to 4.
    .PARAMETER AsArray
        Optional: If set, the output will be in the form of a string array, otherwise a single string is output.
    .EXAMPLE
        $json | ConvertTo-Json | Format-Json -Indentation 2
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Prettify')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$Json,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Minify')]
        [switch]$Minify,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Prettify')]
        [ValidateRange(1, 1024)]
        [int]$Indentation = 4,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Prettify')]
        [switch]$AsArray
    )

    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Minify')
    {
        return ($Json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress
    }

    # If the input JSON text has been created with ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    # then we first need to reconvert it without compression
    if ($Json -notmatch '\r?\n')
    {
        $Json = ($Json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
    }

    $indent = 0
    $regexUnlessQuoted = '(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)'

    $result = $Json -split '\r?\n' |
    ForEach-Object {
        # If the line contains a ] or } character,
        # we need to decrement the indentation level unless it is inside quotes.
        if ($_ -match "[}\]]$regexUnlessQuoted")
        {
            $indent = [Math]::Max($indent - $Indentation, 0)
        }

        # Replace all colon-space combinations by ": " unless it is inside quotes.
        $line = (' ' * $indent) + ($_.TrimStart() -replace ":\s+$regexUnlessQuoted", ': ')

        # If the line contains a [ or { character,
        # we need to increment the indentation level unless it is inside quotes.
        if ($_ -match "[\{\[]$regexUnlessQuoted")
        {
            $indent += $Indentation
        }

        $line
    }

    if ($AsArray) { return $result }
    return $result -Join [Environment]::NewLine
}

# Storage account details
$resourceGroup = "insert resource group here"
$storageAccountName = "insert storage account name here"
$container = "insert container here"
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName

# Creating Storage context for Source, destination and log storage accounts
#$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$context = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString "insert connection string here"
$blob_list = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container -Context $context

foreach($blob_iterator in $blob_list){
     [XML](Get-AzStorageBlobContent $blob_iterator.name -Container $container -Context $context) | ConvertFrom-Xml | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 11 | Format-Json | Set-Content ($blob_iterator.name + '.json')
}
```

Output =

```html
Cannot convert value "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageBlob" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot 
be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
At C:\Users\.....\Convert XML to JSON.ps1:116 char:6
+      [XML](Get-AzStorageBlobContent $blob_iterator.name -Container $c ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument
```

When I run the code the script asks me if I want to download the xml file to a local folder on my laptop.
This is not what I want, I want the conversion to be done in Azure on the Storage container.
And I think that I'm adding ".json" to the .xml file name. 
So the output would become something like filename.xml.json instead of just filename.json

What's going wrong here?
And how can it be fixed?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you tell us what `(Get-AzStorageBlobContent $blob_iterator.name -Container $container -Context $context).ContentType` reveals?

Comment: Write-Output gives: Get-AzStorageBlobContent ... Invoice example.xml
-Container
invoices
-Context

StorageAccountName  : dfsrsupload...
BlobEndPoint        : https://dfsrsupload....blob.core.windows.net/
Context             : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext
StorageAccount      : DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=dfsrsupload...;AccountKey=[key hidden]
TableStorageAccount : DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https
EndPointSuffix      : core.windows.net/
ConnectionString    : DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=dfsrsupload...;AccountKey=...